# SQL Columns to Rows- for a View

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a view which has

```
ID       INQCLASS  INQDETAIL     Period      BAL
1233     GROSS      water     12-3-2017     233.32
1233     GROSS      ENergy    12-3-2017     122.00
```

ID,INQCLASS, Period is same. Except the INQDETAIL  and BAL
I want to combine this into a single row which displays water and energy Bal.

Any Suggestions would be helpful. Thank you

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: i used Group by but getting errors

Comment: I don't know how to use pivot

Comment: Getting Error like this it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple pivot table ought to do it. As long as you know Inqdetail values ahead of time:

```
select ID,
     INQCLASS, 
     [Period], 
     [Water] AS [Water Bal],
     [Energy] as [Energy Bal]
from
(
    select [ID], 
        [INQCLASS], 
        [INQDETAIL], 
        [Period], 
        [BAL] 
    from #util
) As Utilities
PIVOT
(
  SUM([BAL])
  FOR [inqdetail] IN ([Water],[Energy])
 ) AS Pvttbl
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ID, 
    INQCLASS, 
    Period, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN INQDETAIL = 'water' then BAL else 0 end) as WaterBal,
    MAX(CASE WHEN INQDETAIL = 'ENergy' then BAL else 0 end) as ENergyBal
FROM View_Name
GROUP BY ID, INQLASS, Period
```

The case statement serves to show the BAL only when the condition is met. So with case alone, this would still return two rows for each item, but one would have a Waterbal value and no energybal value, and the other would be the reverse.

When you do GROUP BY, every field has to either be in the GROUP BY list (in this case, ID, INQCLASS, Period), or have an aggregate function like SUM, MAX, COUNT, etc. (in this case Waterbal and energyBal have aggregate functions).

The GROUP BY in this case collapses the common ID, INQLASS, Period into single rows, and then takes the largest (MAX) value for Waterbal and energyBal. Since one is always 0, it simply supplies the other one.

Comment: ID is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Thank you, sir. So helpful. Really Appreciate it

Comment: 1 up from me this is the first and perfect answer but it would better to have some description.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT INQDETAIL
, PERIOD
, SUM(BAL) AS energy_Bal       
FROM your_view
WHERE INQDETAIL LIKE 'water'
GROUP BY INQDETAIL
, PERIOD;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It gives me the same output

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
     (SELECT * FROM #temp) AS P
PIVOT
(
   max(bal) FOR INQDETAIL IN ([water], [ENergy])
) AS pv1
```

Comment: Even if your code solves the OP issue, it is recommended to add some of the descriptive text to your code snippet.